# Windows 7 Aero Force on unsupported Graphic card

Tags: windows, aero

I'm new and this is my first question. Can i force Aero on Windows 7 Ultimate? i have a unsupported graphic card vga, 1gb ram, intel 915g, pentium 4, vga, etc. I tried with Blur, Animations and UseMachineCheck in regedit, not result. I tried with windows 7 aero force and show me Aero is active. But no taskbar transparency, etc. Any solution, pls? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but vga driver for 915g isn't compatible with wddm which is required to display aero effects.
You can try some tricks although: http://tweaks.com/windows/39008/enable-vista-glass-on-compatible-hardware/
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/howto-enable-aero-using-intel-915gm-intel-graphics/8e8bfc7c-994f-4172-a0b1-1aa0fd2f825c

Comment: Aero on 1GB RAM will not make you happy, even if you are able to force it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force Aero on an unsupported GPU in Windows 7. You need a GPU with  Pixel Shader 2.0, Dx9 Support and WDDM 1.0 drivers. The 915 never got a WDDM 1.0 driver and so aero can't be used.

In the Pre-Release Version of Windows 8 it was possible to use Aero Glass on the Basic Driver, but Microsoft removed Aero Glass in the RTM of Windows 8.

[image]